# Replace "[" and "]" in string with "," Error can't do that

Tags: java

Hello i have a string Team and members but members are in [ ] and I need to replace [ and ] with  , so I can split the long thingy. When I try to write
`liss.toString().replaceAll("[" , ",");`
i get this error : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0
[

Anyone maybe knows how can I replace "[" and "]" with ","?

Comment: `replaceAll` expects a regex. just use the normal `replace` function. Both will replace all instances of fitting matches. Those 2 methods are just really badly named.

Comment: ... or use `"(\[|\])"`, though just using `replace` is arguably the better option for replacements that aren't complex

Comment: For future questions, please format any code in your question and include a more complete example.  For help on formatting check this out: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks